# What pressure to set for spunding valve

Tags: carbonation, secondary-fermentation

I built a spunding valve and am using it for the first time. I just transferred to my secondary (keg) today and connected my spunding valve.

Seven hours later I already have 5 PSI but was wondering what I should set the pressure at. I’ve read that it should be set to about 15-20 PSI but is that correct for all beer styles?

I brewed an IPA that will finish around 6.8-7% ABV. It’s already at 6.5%.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 PSI during primary.

Then 12-15 PSI based on desired volumes for the style, after primary phases. If you can take gravity reading once your 80-90% of terminal gravity is the time to set carb pressure.

Reason you don't set it to the high psi right away is that c02 and pressure hinders the growth and feeding phase.

Comment: I didn’t use the valve during primary fermentation. Would I still use the suggested secondary fermentation pressure?

Comment: I went ahead and set the pressure at 14psi since I didn't use the valve during primary fermentation. It came out fine.